# Getting a BlockCollection object which contains a Block object

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

What would be the easiet (and possibly fast) way to get a BlockCollection object (System.Windows.Documents namespace) which contains a given Block-type object?

I could not find any direct way of doing this using what's available on Block class.

```
public static BlockCollection FindContainingCollection(Block block)
{
   // ???        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because It's been a month since I posted this and got no answer, I'll post what I ended up doing.  It's rather silly that I wrote this way, but I could not figure out any cleaner way to implement it, mainly because Blocks property is not exposed through a common interface.

```
    public BlockCollection FindContainingCollection(Block block)
    {
        BlockCollection blocks = null;

        FlowDocument flowDoc = block.Parent as FlowDocument;

        if (flowDoc != null)
            blocks = flowDoc.Blocks;
        else
        {
            TableCell tableCell = block.Parent as TableCell;
            if (tableCell != null)
                blocks = tableCell.Blocks;
            else
            {
                ListItem listItem = block.Parent as ListItem;
                if (listItem != null)
                    blocks = listItem.Blocks;
                else
                {
                    Section section = block.Parent as Section;
                    if (section != null)
                        blocks = section.Blocks;
                    else
                    {
                        Figure figure = block.Parent as Figure;
                        if (figure != null)
                            blocks = figure.Blocks;
                        else
                        {
                            Floater floater = block.Parent as Floater;
                            if (floater != null)
                                blocks = floater.Blocks;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return blocks;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ElementAt(int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
for(int i = 0; i < blocks.Count; i++) {
    Block block = blocks.ElementAt(i);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", block.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Block has a property SiblingBlocks which does what you need.

```
BlockCollection containingCollection = block.SiblingBlocks
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.siblingblocks(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Have edited it to include a code example.

It's just a property so the method in the question doesn't need to exist.